# Prove that $\mathbf{L}$ is almost a normal modal logic.

Tags: logic, proof-theory, modal-logic

> Suppose we have a logic $\mathbf{L}$ containing all the propositional tautologies and the formula $\square(p\wedge q)\leftrightarrow(\square p \wedge\square q)$, and it is  closed by Modus Ponens, Substitution and the following rule (R): if $\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi\in\mathbf{L}$ then $\square\varphi\leftrightarrow\square\psi\in\mathbf{L}$. Prove that $\square(p\to q)\to(\square p\to\square q)\in\mathbf{L}$.

I'm really stuck with this exercise. I'm used to propositional calculus, where Modus Ponens and Deduction Thereom are the main tools. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you have copied the exercise correctly? Because this claim is false, so it's not surprising that you cannot prove it. I suspect that the actual exercise has, or at any rate should have, $\Box (p \wedge q) \leftrightarrow (\Box p \wedge \Box q)$ instead of $\Box (p \wedge q) \rightarrow (\Box p \wedge \Box q)$.

Comment: Yes, you're  right! But I still don't know how to start :(

Comment: You can start by observing that what you want to prove is equivalent to $(\Box (p\to q) \wedge \Box p) \to \Box q$, and moreover $p \wedge q$ is equivalent to $p \wedge (p \to q)$.

Comment: I think it is preferable to write $\operatorname{\square} \varphi$ (with "\operatorname{\square}" made into an alias for best practice ;) ) rather than $\square \varphi$.

Comment: In fact, you wish to show is that $\mathbf{L}$ satisfies the **Distribution Axiom**. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbf{L}$ contains all propositionnal tautologies, you have
$$ \Big(p \wedge (p \to q) \Big) \longleftrightarrow \Big(p \wedge q \Big) \in \mathbf{L}$$

whence $$ \Big(\operatorname{\square} p \wedge \operatorname{\square} (p\to q) \Big)  \longleftrightarrow \Big(\operatorname{\square} p \wedge \operatorname{\square} q \Big) \in \mathbf{L}$$

Since $\mathbf{L}$ is closed under Modus Ponens, we get the weakening :
$$ \Big(\operatorname{\square} p \wedge \operatorname{\square} (p\to q) \Big)  \longrightarrow \operatorname{\square} q $$
which is logically equivalent to the Distribution Axiom indeed :
$$\Big(\operatorname{\square} p \wedge \operatorname{\square} (p\to q) \Big)  \longrightarrow \operatorname{\square} q \equiv \operatorname{\square} (p\to q) \longrightarrow (\operatorname{\square} p \to \operatorname{\square} q)$$
Hence the conclusion since $\mathbf{L}$ is closed under substitutions.